# radio buttons not checked in UI but checked in HTML in Partial View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, radio-button, partial-views

I am having a partial view which has textbox, drop-down-list and readio buttons. I have to load this partial view on a view in a for loop. textbox and drop-down controls in the partial view are getting populated properly but radio-buttons are not. When the last time the partial view loads in the for loop radio-buttons are also populated properly (as desired) from the model that I am passing to the partial view. My partial view calling code is as below:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_PDFReportPartialView.cshtml", item)
```

here "item" is the model. and my radio-buttons are given below (From the partial view...)

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.RadioButton("Job_Type", true, new { style = "width:15px; background-color:Window;", @class = "radiobuttonlist", @id = "Job_Type_" + @Model.ReportID, @name = "Job_Type_" + @Model.ReportID }) Support
    @Html.RadioButton("Job_Type", false, new { style = "width:15px; background-color:Window;", @class = "radiobuttonlist", @id = "Job_Type_" + @Model.ReportID, @name = "Job_Type_" + @Model.ReportID }) Installation
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Job_Type)
</div>
```

When I see the view source I see that radio-buttons are checked properly as below:

```
<input checked="checked" class="radiobuttonlist" id="Job_Type_66" name="Job_Type" style="width:15px; background-color:Window;" type="radio" value="False" />
```

Can anybody help me here?

Comment: Show your models and the loop in the main view. Using a partial in a loop means you will not be able to bind to your collection when you post back anyway so this is not the correct approach. You need to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for your type.

Comment: I do not have a requirement to post back this page. I just want to download a pdf from this view once it is rendered. I am using rotative pdf for this. I guess the problem is with the name property of radio-button input control. Can we assign name dynamically to radio-button list.

Comment: What is the purpose of radio buttons if you not going to post anything. And what is the point of `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for a boolean property? And what is the point of trying to set the `name` attribute (which does not work anyway). What are you tying to do with this?

Comment: I simply put "new { Name = "Job_Type_" + @Model.ReportID }" and it worked. Thanks for your input Stephen.

Comment: OMG. You really need to learn some basics of MVC

Comment: Stephen I am just fetching data from database in my model and trying to display it in a view. Simple.

Comment: Yes I am just a beginner in MVC